# keeping local profile a different domain user

Tags: administrator, active-directory, user-profiles

My question is about how to log in to a machine with a (newly joined) domain user account, while keeping the local user's settings/profile which have been established by the previous domain user (outlook account, desktop, etch.

I could probably go to active directory and rename the old domain user to the new one, but wouldn't that mess up local and domain profiles?
Any proposals?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most of user activity is controlled by SID's not name so even naming the same in AD windows will see it as a different account by the SID. Really it should be done manually to transfer bits across the new user account, you can export certain Registry settings for Outlook accounts but even be careful with this as you can corrupt the local account and have to recreate it from scratch...

Comment: What is the SID that you mention?

Comment: the SID is the Security Identifier in a Windows infrastructure and is unique across all objects in AD so users, groups, etc. all have a unique SID. In the windows registry you have a profilelist section which sets the SID to the user path you can find this under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\.... those entries in that list are SID's